# Proof of least upper bound and greatest lower bound property of an ordered set

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, order-theory

I am currently self-studying topology using the book of Munkres and since I am completely new to this topic (engineering grad) I need your opinion/verification regarding the proof that I came up with for the exercise 3.13. It seems to me a little bit simpler (though maybe not correct) comparing to [this one](http://web.math.ku.dk/%7Emoller/e02/3gt/opg/S03.pdf).

> Prove the following:
>
> Theorem. If an ordered set A has the least upper bound property, then it has the greatest lower bound property.

If A has the least upper bound property then there is $A_0\subset A$ with $A_0$ bounded above and $c = \sup \{A_0\} \in A$, with $x\leq c$ for any $x \in A_0 \subset A$. Now consider the singleton subset $A_1 = \{c\} \subset A$, consisting of only the element $c$, which is bounded below. Assuming that $A$ does not have the greatest lower bound property, then $\inf \{A_1\}\notin A$, but $\inf\{A_1\}=c \in A$. Thus, by contradiction, the set $A$ must also have the greatest lower bound property. $\square$

> Edit:
> Since the above attempt to prove the theorem is clearly false, I post
> a revised one, according to the hint provided by @fleablood.

Let $B_0$ be any subset of $A$ that is bounded below and $A_0$ the set of all lower bounds of $B_0$ in A, i.e. $A_0 = \{ x \in A\ |\ x \leq x_0, \forall x_0 \in B_0 \}$. Then the set $A_0$ is bounded above since there is $x_0 \in B_0 \subset A$ such that $x \leq x_0$ for all $x \in A_0$. Assuming now that the set $A$ has the l.u.b. property, we can write $c = \sup \{ A_0\} \in A$ and $x \leq c \leq x_0$,  $\forall x \in A_0$, $\forall x_0 \in B_0$, because if there is $x_0 \in B_0$ such that $x_0 < c$ then $c$ would not be the l.u.b. of $A_0$. That also means that $c\in A_0$ (from the definition of $A_0$) and thus $c$ is the g.l.b. of $B_0$ which exists in $A$. Conversely, let $B_0$ be any subset of $A$ that is bounded above and $A_0$ the set of all upper bounds of $B_0$ in $A$. In a similar way we conclude that if the set $A$ has the g.l.b. property it must also have the l.u.b. property. $\square$

Could you please confirm me if it's correct or if there are still holes or false arguments?

Comment: Poorly written.  There is $A_0$... is the wrong start.  Let $A_0$ be any subset... is getting off on the right foot.  The rest was bumpy at best.

Comment: Let $A_0$ be any subset... is another way of saying that there is arbitrary $A_0$, but I am missing the word `arbitrary', that's your point? By bumpy you mean badly written or incorrect?

Comment: No.  Not having the greatest lower  bound property doesn't mean that greatest lower bound never exists.  It just means it doesn't always have to exist.  And there is *nothing* important about $c=A_1$.  You could make the *exact* same argument with any $\{d\}: d\in A$.  Does that mean *every* ordered set has the greatest lower bound property?  If so there really wasn't any point in making a definition for it.

Comment: "By bumpy you mean badly written or incorrect?"  I suspect he meant badly written because he didn't bother reading it.  It started out okay (albeit badly written) but... it *is* incorrect.  You seem to thing l.u.b/g.l.b property means either i) sets can be bounded above/below or that it means ii) l.u.b/g.l.b might exist.  The l.u.b/g.l.b property does not mean either of those.  It mean l.u.b/g.l.b *must* *always* exist.

Comment: #fleablood No, for example for the ordered set $B = (-1,0) \cup (0,1)$ taking just a $\{ d : d \in A\}$ wouldn't work, but that's where my point is (if it is a point at all) that there are $ x \leq c $ in $A$ and also $c \in A$.

Comment: $c$ is in $A$ no matter how you came up with it.  There are $x \le c$ for *every* $c \in A$.  The fact that $c =\sup A_0$ has nothing to do with anything.  If we pick $k$ being *ANY* element in $A$ we would still have $x \le k$ exist and $\inf \{k\} = k \in A$.  That doesn't prove anything.

Comment: #fleablood It is actually the definition of the l.u.b. property that "If A has the least upper bound property then there is $A_0\subset A$ with $A_0$ bounded above, and $c = \sup \{A_0\} \in A$, with $x\leq c$ for any $x \in A_0 \subset A$"

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ does *not* have the least upper bound property.  Take $k = \frac 13$.  Then there exist $x \le \frac 13$.  And $A_1 = \{\frac 13\} \subset \mathbb Q$.  And $\inf \{\frac 13\} = \frac 13$.  Does that prove that $\mathbb Q$ has the greatest lower bound property?

Comment: #fleablood The $k$ that I am using though is not random, is the $\sup\{A_0\} \in A$.

Comment: You misunderstood what that means.  It doesn't mean that *some* $A_0$ exist.  It means that ever *every* nonempty set, $A_0$ that is bounded above then there *will* be a $c$ that is $\sup A_0$.  Which means that for any $x\in A_0$ you will have $x \le c$ but ALSO that for any $c_0 < c$ that will *not* be the case... note: $\sup (0,2) = 2$ but $2.25$ is *ALSO* an upper bound.  for all $x \in (0,2)$ we have $x \le 2.25$.  But $2.25$ isn't the *LEAST* number with this property.

Comment: "The k that I am using though is not random, is the sup{A0}∈A."  So what?  I know that.  But that doesn't make *ANY* difference.  It'd be true for *ANY* number.

Comment: What you have to prove is that if there is *ANY* set $B_0\subset A$ where $B_0$ is bounded *BELOW* and that $B_0$ might have *nothing* whatsoever to do with $A_0$, you must prove that $B_0$ has a greatest lower bound.

Comment: " No, for example for the ordered set A=(−1,0)∪(0,1) taking just a {d:d∈A} wouldn't work, but that's where my point is (if it is a point at all) that there are x≤c in A and also c∈A"  Okay, take $\{.75\}$.  There are $x \le .75$ in $A$ and $.75 \in A$.

Comment: Let $A = [0, 25]$ and let $A_0 = (3, 17)$ and let $c = \sup (3,17) = 17$ and let $A_1 = \{17\}$.  and $\inf A_1 = 17$.  Okay.... So what?  How does that prove that $B_0 = (2.35, 5)$ has a $\inf B_0$?  You must prove that $B_0$ also has and $\inf$ and you must prove $(\frac {28}{39}, 14)\cup {16,23}$ has an $\inf$ and *EVERY* set that is bounded below has an $\inf$.  How are you going to do that?

Comment: Here's a hint.  If $B$ is bounded below it will have at least one, and possibly many lower bounds.  Let $A_0 = ${ all the lower bounds of $B$}.  My questions for you is.  1) Is $A_0$ bounded above?  2)  Does $c=\sup A_0$ exist? 3) is $c$ a lower bound of $B$?  What is the greatest lower bound of $B$?

Comment: #fleablood Ok, I got it. I had taken a false negation (for the g.l.b. property) and got the wrong path. I am gonna work it again and reach back. Thanks!

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for the hint, I have posted a new proof according to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If A has the least upper bound property then there is A0⊂A with A0 bounded above

That'd be true if $A$ *didn't* have the least upper bound property.  You can *always* find a set that is bounded above or below.  The question is whether *every* such set will *always* have a least upper bound.

Example:  Let $A_0 = \{q| q^2 < 2\} \subset \mathbb Q$.  That *IS* bounded above by $2$.  But $2$ is not the *least* upper bound.  There is no least upper bound for *that* set.

Also *not* having the least upper bound property doesn't mean that a least upper bound *doesn't* exist.

Example:  Let $B = \{q| q < 3\}\subset \mathbb Q$.  $\sup B$ *does* exist and $\sup B = 3$.  Even though $\mathbb Q$ *doesn't* have the least upper bound property.  In $\mathbb Q$, $B$ has a least upper bound.... and $A$ does not..

> c=sup{A0}∈A, with x≤c for any x∈A0⊂A

Okay.  $A$ *does* have the least upper bound property so $c = \sup A_0$ does exist.  That's true.

> Now consider the singleton subset A1={c}⊂A, consisting of only the element c, which is bounded below.

That'd be true of *any* singleton set, whether $A$ had the least upper bound principal or not.

Consider $A = \mathbb Q$ and $A_0=\{q| q < 3\}$ and $\sup A_0 = c$.

Now let $A_1 = \{c\} = \{3\}$.

Nothing interesting is going to come from this.....

> Assuming that A does not have the greatest lower bound property, then inf{A1}∉A

Nonsense.  $\mathbb Q$ does not have the greatest lower bound property but $\inf \{3\} = 3$.

Not having the greatest lower bound doesn't mean a greatest lower bound *can't* exist.  It just means it doesn't *have* to exist.

$B=\{q| q^2 > 3\} \subset Q$ is such that $\inf B$ does not exist.

But $\inf A_1 = \inf \{c\} = c$ does.